# Rename parts/assembly's inside assembly

Tags: vb.net, autodesk-inventor

I have a program made that can place files in a assembly or open that file and rename them and places them in to the right folder. I want to do the same thing with small assembly's but I can't get it to work because I need to rename and place the parts in the right folder before I place or open them.

the code that I have is this;

```vb
Dim oDoc As AssemblyDocument
oDoc = _invApp.ActiveDocument
'Dim oDoc As String = "K:\Flenzen\BundNutPakking\DN10 19 - DIN11864-2.iam"
Dim acd As AssemblyComponentDefinition
acd = oDoc.ComponentDefinition

Dim oPath As String = "C:\Thomas de Vries\K20TEST\"

Dim refDocs As DocumentsEnumerator = oDoc.AllReferencedDocuments
Dim compCount As Integer = refDocs.Count
Dim refDoc As Document
For j = 1 To compCount
    refDoc = refDocs.Item(j)
    'If the component in assembly is part then save it to "Parts" folder
    If refDoc.DocumentType = DocumentTypeEnum.kPartDocumentObject Then
        refDoc.SaveAs(oPath & "02 - Onderdelen\" & j & ".ipt", False)
        'If the component in assembly is subassembly then save it to "Assembly" folder
    ElseIf refDoc.DocumentType = DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject Then
        refDoc.SaveAs(oPath & "03 - Samenstellingen\" & j & ".iam", False)
    End If
Next

'Saving a copy of the assembly document
oDoc.SaveAs(oPath & "03 - Samenstellingen\Newassemname.iam", False)
```

What this code does is this:
1 You need to have a assembly open (that's not what I wan't).
2 It checks how many Parts/assembly's are in the assembly.
3 it gives the parts/assembly's a new name and places them in te folder.
4 the master assembly is placed in a folder and has given a new name.

what I wan't is like this:
1 Get the parts/assembly's from "K:\Flenzen\BundNutPakking\DN10 19 - DIN11864-2.iam".
2 Rename the parts/assembly's whitin and put them in a folder.
3 rename master assembly and put it in the right folder.
( all this without to have open the file )
4 Place the master assembly of the new location you gave at step 4 or open it.

I hope one of you have experience with this and can help me!
Many thanks in advance.

Bye,
Thomas de Vries

Comment: So you want to pick up all the folders in directory and copy them to a new directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I got it to work finally this morning.

This is how I did it;

1: I opend the assembly I want to copy
2: save the parts inside to an new location that I wan't (so I have al my connections right)
3: save the assembly I just eddited to a new location
4: close the assembly
5: open the new assembly of the place you just saved it to.

This is the code I use:

```
           Dim oDoc As Document
            oDoc = _invApp.Documents.Open(oLocatie)


            Dim osDoc As AssemblyDocument
            osDoc = _invApp.ActiveDocument

            Dim acd As AssemblyComponentDefinition
            acd = osDoc.ComponentDefinition

            Dim refDocs As DocumentsEnumerator = osDoc.AllReferencedDocuments
            Dim compCount As Integer = refDocs.Count
            Dim refDoc As Document

            For Each refDoc In refDocs
                Dim subFilenaam1 As String = refDoc.FullFileName
                Dim subFilenaam As String = subFilenaam1.Substring(subFilenaam1.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                'For j = 1 To compCount
                Dim subsFilenaam As String
                subsFilenaam = Replace(subFilenaam, "KW", nName & "-" & Standardpartnummer)



                'refDoc = refDocs.Item(j)
                'If the component in assembly is part then save it to "Parts" folder
                If refDoc.DocumentType = DocumentTypeEnum.kPartDocumentObject Then
                    refDoc.SaveAs(nLocatie & nName & "\02 - Onderdelen\" & subsFilenaam, False)
                    'If the component in assembly is subassembly then save it to "Assembly" folder
                ElseIf refDoc.DocumentType = DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject Then
                    refDoc.SaveAs(nLocatie & nName & "03 - Samenstellingen\" & subsFilenaam, False)
                End If
                'Next
            Next
            oDoc.SaveAs(nLocatie & nName & "\03 - Samenstellingen\" & Filenaam, False)

            Call oDoc.Close()

            Dim oNewDoc As Inventor.Document
            oNewDoc = _invApp.Documents.Open(nLocatie & nName & "\03 - Samenstellingen\" & Filenaam)

        ElseIf nFilesoort = "ipt" Then

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(nLocatie & nFilenaam) Then
                MsgBox("Filebestaat al, er moet nog even die autonummering er in geplaats worden!")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                IO.File.Copy(oLocatie, nLocatie & nFilenaam)
            End If

            Dim oDoc As Document
            oDoc = _invApp.Documents.Open(nLocatie & nFilenaam)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change location of the files in the assembly document, the best tool for this is *ApprenticeServerComponent*. This is COM component for work with iProperties, file references and more. See Inventor SDK or following links for samples.

https://modthemachine.typepad.com/my_weblog/2010/03/iproperties-without-inventor-apprentice.html

https://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2012/08/replace-the-file-reference-by-inventor-api.html